# How to access a value inside the callback from the global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express Js and I want to export the port on which the server is running for some testing purpose. But the port seems to be only available inside callback function of `app.listen`.Is there any way I can export the port?

```
let server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', ()=>{
let port = server.address().port;
})
// accesss port here
module.export = port; // what I want
```

Answer (score 4):

You could put a Promise as the export which resolves to the port:

```
module.exports.portProm = new Promise((resolve) => {
  const server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    resolve(server.address().port);
  });
});
```

and do

```
require('server.js').portProm.then((port) => {
  // use port here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the first parameter is the port the server *should* listen to, why not just pass a specific port in the first place?

```
const port = 3042;
let server = app.listen(port, 'localhost');

module.exports = port;
```

---

**edit**

~~Defining the variable outside the callback should do the trick:~~

**It doesn't, because the app resolves asynchronously.**

```
let port;

let server = app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    port = server.address().port;
});

// accesss port here
module.exports = port;
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `module.exports = port;` will run before the callback when `port` is undefined.

Comment: Im already passing a port from my config file. I intend to write a test to see if the port on which server is running is one that i passed via config.

Comment: @ggorien: Right. Corrected that bit.
OP: Got it. In that case CertainPerformance's answer should help.